# mypy django rest framework - Unsupported left operand type when multiple permission classes are used

Tags: python, django, mypy, typeshed, django-stubs

I am integrating mypy on a existing codebase(using django, drf frameworks).

Sample code in view.py:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser, IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly

@api_view()
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly | IsAdminUser])
def listAbc(request):
    queryset = ...
    serializer = ...
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Result:

```
$ mypy
error: Unsupported left operand type for | ("Type[IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]")
```

Plugins used:

```
$ pip list | grep stubs
django-stubs                    1.2.0
djangorestframework-stubs       1.0.0
```

mypy configuration file (mypy.ini):

```
[mypy]

plugins =
    mypy_django_plugin.main, mypy_drf_plugin.main

;ignore_missing_imports = True
files=**/*.py

[mypy-*.migrations.*]
ignore_errors = True

[mypy.plugins.django-stubs]
django_settings_module = project.settings
```

Checked with both mypy (0.720 and 0.740).

What could be the issue here ?
Since the operation '|' is not recognized by mypy, I suspect the metaclass BasePermissionMetaclass (containing the operations) is not added BasePermission during mypy evaluation. I assume just installing  djangorestframework-stubs and configuring the same in mypy.ini is enough.

Comment: can you show how you imported these classes?

Answer (score 0):

The issue if because mypy doesn't understand the `|` operator being used between two permission classes in Django rest framework. This is a limitation of the mypy and type stubs for Django and DRF, atleast until now(probably gonna get solved some day).

The `|` operator is overloaded in DRF's BasePermission class to mean `"or"`, allowing multiple permissions to be combined, But mypy doesn't recognize this operator overloading, so we have the error!

Instead of using the `|` operator, you can create a custom permission class that encapsulates the logic of the two permission classes. For example:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission, IsAdminUser, IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly

class CustomPermission(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly().has_permission(request, view) or IsAdminUser().has_permission(request, view)

@api_view()
@permission_classes([CustomPermission])
def listAbc(request):
    queryset = ...
    serializer = ...
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

The question is like 4 years old, just came across and thought it may be helpful for someone searching it!